# How to apply groupBy and aggregate functions to a specific window in a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to apply a `groupBy` and a subsequent `agg` function to a PySpark DataFrame, but only to a specific window. This is best illustrated by an example. Suppose that I have a dataset named `df`:

```py
df.show()

    +-----+----------+----------+-------+
    |   ID| Timestamp| Condition|  Value|
    +-----+----------+----------+-------+
    |   z1|         1|         0|     50|
|-------------------------------------------|
|   |   z1|         2|         0|     51|   |
|   |   z1|         3|         0|     52|   |
|   |   z1|         4|         0|     51|   |
|   |   z1|         5|         1|     51|   |
|   |   z1|         6|         0|     49|   |
|   |   z1|         7|         0|     44|   |
|   |   z1|         8|         0|     46|   |
|-------------------------------------------|
    |   z1|         9|         0|     48|
    |   z1|        10|         0|     42|
 +-----+----------+----------+-------+
```

Particularly, what I would like to do is to apply a kind of window of +- 3 rows to the row where column `Condition == 1` (i.e. in this case, row 5). Within that window, as depicted in the above DataFrame, I would like to find the minimum value of column `Value` and the corresponding value of column `Timestamp`, thus obtaining:

```py
+----------+----------+
| Min_value| Timestamp|
+----------+----------+
|        44|         7|
+----------+----------+
```

Does anyone know how this can be tackled?

Many thanks in advance

Marioanzas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window that spans between 3 preceding and 3 following rows, get the minimum, and filter the condition:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'min',
    F.min(
        F.struct('Value', 'Timestamp')
    ).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Timestamp').rowsBetween(-3,3))
).filter('Condition = 1').select('min.*')

df2.show()
+-----+---------+
|Value|Timestamp|
+-----+---------+
|   44|        7|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Hi @mck! Many thanks for your suggestion. However, this would definitely work for datasets where there is only one row containing `Condition == 1`. However, I do not think if would work for datasets where I have two or more rows with `Condition == 1`. Do you agree?

Comment: @Marioanzas yes, I realised that was a bad solution. I rewrote it and it should hopefully do the job much better now